# Sumif formula gives array arguments to Sumifs are of different sizes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the formula as given below in Google Sheet. It keeps giving the error "array arguments to Sumifs are of different sizes" . As far as I can tell I believe the arguments are of same size, so not able to understand the issue.

```
=sumifs(TimeSheet!$B$2:$B$5,Month(TimeSheet!$A$2:$A$5),5,Year(TimeSheet!$A$2:$A5),2020)
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a demo sheet where you are facing this issue?

Comment: It will be difficult to share sheet as it contains lot of other data. But let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your formula is that you are using arrays (range of multiple cells) to MONTH and YEAR functions: they return a single value.